# Ember combining route data

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a situation where I have a route extending another route but will add more data to this new route. What made it tricky is we want to merge the new data with the existing base route.

I can do this synchronously in the model hook with

```
return Ember.merge(this._super(...arguments), {
  foo : 123
});
```

But how can I retrieve data asynchronously and still use this `Ember.merge`, ie something like

```
model(){
  return Ember.merge(this._super(...arguments), {
    foo : 123
    baa: store.get('smthElse')
  });
}
```

will give me back a model with `baa` as a promise object, not with its resolved value.

I tried returning the `Ember.merge` inside of the `store.get('smthElse).then` but the `this._super(...arguments)` threw undefined errors.

Answer (score 0):

The `model` hook returns a promise so you must wait for it to resolve with a value before merging.

If the object you're merging with also returns a promise, you must wait for that promise as well.

If the two promises can be created in parallel, something like this should work:

```
model(){
  return Ember.RSVP.all([
    this._super(...arguments), // call parent route's model hook
    store.get('smthElse')      // call whatever else you need
  ])
  .then(                       // wait for all promises to resolve before merging
    ([parentModel, somethingElse]) => (
      Ember.merge(parentModel, {
        foo : 123,
        baa: somethingElse
      });
    )
  );
}
```

Otherwise, if the request `store.get('smthElse')` depends on the parent route's model, you should chain the calls instead:

```
model(){
  return this._super(...arguments) // call parent route's model hook
    .then(
      // request something else with the resolved parent model in scope
      (parentModel) => store.get('smthElse', parentModel.get('whtvr')).then(
        // resolve with both the parent model and something else
        (somethingElse) => ({
          parentModel,
          somethingElse
        })
      )
    ) 
    .then(
      ({ parentModel, somethingElse }) => (
        Ember.merge(parentModel, {
          foo : 123,
          baa: somethingElse
        });
      )
    );
}
```